# Get accessToken from power BI without GUI authentication

Tags: java, azure, powerbi

I followed the instruction provided in the power BI web app authentication document and am able to get the authentication token. But the procedure requires the user t enter the credential in GUI to get the authentication code.

Instead, I want to do silent authentication i.e. without GUI authentication. I tried couple approaches like using HHTPClient and reference code in the below link

https://gist.github.com/dquig/a4f2f02fe3e306cebe2e

But it asks for client_secret , unfortunately there is no method accepting cleint_secret along with resourceuri, clientId, username, password, callback. am Using azure adal4j of 1.0.0 version. Is that a version issue? Any help will be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Due to using the Client app to get Azure AD access token, it is necessary for inputting the username and password on GUI authentication. If following the web app authentication (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143610.aspx ) to do authentication, it meets the `client_secret` requirement.

So I used the endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token` to get access token from Power BI and made a console application sample in Java.

Here is my maven dependencies configuration below in `pom.xml` file.
It's fine for using Azure adal4j of 1.0.0 version, but suggest to update the latest version.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the sample code as below.

```
String clientId = "<clientId>";
String clientSecret = "<key>";
String tenantId = "<tenantId>";
String authority =String.format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token", tenantId);
String resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
AuthenticationContext context = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;
ExecutorService service = null;
try {
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service);
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resource, credential, null);
    result = future.get();
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
String accessToken = null;
if (result == null) {
    throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
} else {
    accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);
}
```

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

---

Update for C#：

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
{
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("{authorityURL}");  
  var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "{application id}", clientSecret: "{application password}");
  var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "{resourceURL}", clientCredential:credential);

  if (result == null) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
  }

  string token = result.AccessToken;

  return token;
}
```

Please see the reference for `AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479466.aspx.

Comment: I am trying this in C# with this code, but still get 403 Forbidden

string authority = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/auth2/token", tenantID);

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", clientCredential: credential);

Comment: @ChrisHarrington There was a sample for PowerBI in C# that you can refer to, please see https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/blob/master/samples/consoleapp/getting-started-for-dotnet/PBIGettingStarted/PBIGettingStarted/Program.cs. Also, you can try to use a third party library wrapped REST API for PowerBI as reference, see https://github.com/Vtek/PowerBI.Api.Client.

Comment: All of those samples require the user to login. I need to code a non-interactive authentication since this job runs on a schedule.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Hi, the code in my post is that a non-interactive authentication process in Java to get the access token.

Comment: But when I try it in C# I get a 403 error. Do you have a C# version?

Comment: @ChrisHarrington For C# version, please refer to https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-client-app/.

Comment: That version isn't non-interactive.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington I updated the C# code in my post. The Class `AuthenticationContext` has many methods with the same name `AcquireToken`. The non-interactive method only need two arguments: `resource` & `ClientCredential`. You can refer to the code in the step 7 at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-service-principal-with-password---powershell.

Comment: That code sample still give a 403 Forbidden. I'm not sure exactly what you were referring to with "my post". I tried it with the code in "step 7". I get the 403 when I try to use the token.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Could you create a new thread for talking about your code in C# carefully? In this way, our discussion here will not deviate too much from the original issue. This will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. 
Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Absolutely. Will do that now.

Comment: New at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692974/how-to-connect-to-power-bi-api-using-non-interactive-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at this blog post: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/

The ADAL .NET client library APIs now have method that accept the user name and password.  The article includes a listing of all the constraints and limitations. If your use does not fall within the happy path, I think you'll need to prompt the user.

I should mention that if you store the refresh token for the user you should only have to prompt them once every 90 days (or whenever the refresh token expires).

Comment: I tried that approach but it is asking for client_silent along with all other credentials like , ClientId, username, password. More over am trying using java. I have give the link in my original post the approach which i tried. Which is exactly the same what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you register your app as a native client app then you would need to provide a client secret. You would then be able to use the username and password flow without going through the interactive login.