# how to connect to Power BI API using non-interactive authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, powerbi

Coding in C#.
I'm following this guide:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-service-principal-with-password---powershell%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B

But it is not working and it is not Power BI specific so I'm not sure exactly how to apply it to the Power BI API.

In my attempt to connect to Power BI I am getting a 403 Forbidden response.

```
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + Properties.Settings.Default.TenantID);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: Properties.Settings.Default.ClientID, clientSecret: Properties.Settings.Default.ClientSecretKey);
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string accessToken = result.AccessToken;


        string responseContent = string.Empty;

        //The resource Uri to the Power BI REST API resource
        string datasetsUri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";

        //Configure datasets request
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(datasetsUri) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));

        try
        {

            //Get datasets response from request.GetResponse()
            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            {
                //Get reader from response stream
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    //Deserialize JSON string
                    //JavaScriptSerializer class is in System.Web.Script.Serialization
                    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    Datasets datasets = (Datasets)json.Deserialize(responseContent, typeof(Datasets));

                    resultsTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
                    //Get each Dataset from 
                    foreach (dataset ds in datasets.value)
                    {
                        resultsTextbox.Text += String.Format("{0}\t{1}\n", ds.Id, ds.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            resultsTextbox.Text = wex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried the whole process again. Some additional details:

1. created a web app; 

2. APPLICATION IS MULTI-TENANT: No; 

3. USER ASSIGNMENT REQUIRED TO ACCESS APP: No; 

4. Added "permissions to other applications" to "Power BI Service" with all 9 delegated permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the resource URI:

```
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);
```

to

```
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: **"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"**, clientCredential: credential);
```

You want to acquire a token for the power bi api.

Hope that Helps.

**EDIT Updating Answer Based on OP Comment:**

Here is what you will need to do.

In Azure AD create a "Native App" and get that client ID there will be NO Secret.

Make sure you have the latest version of ADAL from Nuget Active Directory Authentication Library 2.23.302261847

You will need to use this Acquire Token Overload:

```
authContext.AcquireToken("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", clientID, new UserCredential(<Username>, <Password>));
```

**EDIT: 2016-11-11**

**ADAL 3.13.7** UserCredentail no longer has a constructor as defined above.  There is a new sealed class UserPasswordCredential

```
public sealed class UserPasswordCredential : UserCredential
```

Which has the constructor that matches the former UserCredential object

```
public UserPasswordCredential(string userName, string password)
```

You can acquire the token by doing this:

```
authContext.AcquireToken("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", clientID, new UserPasswordCredential(<Username>, <Password>));
```

Comment: I gave that a try. It does return a token. But when I try the datasets call I still get 403 Forbidden

Comment: Yes, that works. But I am trying to do this with a service account and not with a user credential.

Comment: What do you mean by service account?  Do you mean Service Principal, the ClientId/Secret from the Azure AD Web App setup?  I don't think that is possible, I cannot find anything that explicitly states user credentials are needed to access the api but it looks that way.  Otherwise your original code should have worked without a hitch.  If you are not using user credentials then how would a call to get datasets work? Go through all users in the tenant and get their datasets? Doesn't seem like its designed that way.

Comment: You bring up a good point - and one that logically does lean to the outcome I see. Other APIs that I use address this by having a "admin" scope that gives permissions across all tenant resources. Microsoft, is this indeed this issue? Would adding such a scope make sense?

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do and the only way that I could think of doing this would be to first add a "Service Account" in office 365 with power bi access.  Then create different groups in PowerBI and assign that user to all groups.  Then make sure anyone else who creates power bi reports do them in the specified groups.  That way you can use the ONE Office365 account to access all the possible data sets across all groups. That make sense?

Comment: I could kiss you! Spent a day on this!

Comment: Last Active Directory Authentication Library have not constructor with username and password for 'UserCredential'. Can you update your solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tuition in PowerBI website: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-what-you-need-to-create-an-app/.

The article has detailed guide that how to create a PowerBI web app, include registering a application in Azure AD and get the ClientID so on. These steps are not difficult to understand and follow. Let me know if it is your need. Keep contact if you have any questions.

There is a simple sample in this page: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/

Comment: That is not a non-interactive sample (it posts a login dialog).  I need to do this non-interactively.

Comment: ok, I test your code and change ` string datasetsUri = "api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";;` to my own url, it has no 403 error.

Comment: did you create the group named ‘myorg’？

Comment: You tested with Power BI? Then you would know that "myorg" is not a group. It is part of the API spec: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203567.aspx

Comment: I see the sentence: `To learn how to create a group, see Create a group.
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets`

Comment: Yes, true. But when called with /myorg/datasets it returns the non-grouped datasets.

Comment: this url is not found https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/